# Is there a way to make a shallow copy of a constant struct to a non-constant struct?

Tags: c, struct, constants, shallow-copy

I want to make a shallow copy on an entire struct which has the constant deceleration. But I want the struct that I am copying too to be non constant.

This is what I have done so far which is producing an error:

```
struct Student{
    char *name;
    int age;
    Courses *list;  //First course (node)
}Student;

void shallowCopy(const Student *one){
    Student oneCopy = malloc(sizeof(one));

    oneCopy = one;     <--------------- ERROR POINTS TO THIS LINE
}
```

The compiler error I am getting:

```
Assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type.
```

I know I can remove the `const` from one or add the `const` to `oneCopy`, but I want to know if there is a way to make a shallow copy in this specific situation where `Student one` is a `const` and the copy `Student oneCopy` is not.

Comment: Why the down vote? Is this not a valid, unique question that displays what I have attempted.

Comment: I didn't vote, but the -1 could be because there are extremely basic mistakes here that would be covered by any introductory book or course.  Also you didn't post your actual code: you should get a compile error on the line `void shallowCopy(const Student *one){`; and another one on the `malloc` line, and a different error on the indicated line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
Student* oneCopy = malloc(sizeof(*one));
*oneCopy = *one;
```

Because you want to assign the struct, not the pointer.

Comment: You really don't even need the `malloc()` call.  Direct assignment works as well:  `Student two = *one;`.